# Run jar application from a springboot server

Tags: java, spring-boot, jar

I am running a springboot server. 
This server has some webservices. 
One of those services has to run an external jar when it receives a request. Actually the server is the interface between a calculation engine (the jar), and the user. 
There is the code :

```
public class Launcher extends Thread{

@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    runJar(this.getJar(), this.getArgs());

}






private void runJar(String jar, String[] args){
    try {
        String[] s = new String[4+args.length];
        s[0] = "nohup";
        s[1] = "java";
        s[2] = "-jar";
        s[3] = jar;
        for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++){
            s[i+4] = args[i];
        }
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(s);

        //Process exec = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"mkdir", "monTest"});


    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("failed");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
}

public class Memory {

private ArrayList<Integer> startedIds;

public ArrayList<Integer> getStartedIds() {
    return startedIds;
}

public void setStartedIds(ArrayList<Integer> startedIds) {
    this.startedIds = startedIds;
}

public Memory() {
    this.startedIds = new ArrayList<>();
}

public Memory(ArrayList<Integer> arr) {
    this.startedIds = arr;
}

public int start() {
    int id = this.findAvailableId();
    this.getStartedIds().add(id);
    System.out.println("i'm going to start with a big command!+uhpop");
    String[] args = {"arg1","arg2", "arg3", "&"};
    Launcher launcher = new Launcher("myJar.jar", args);
    launcher.start();


    return id;
}

private int findAvailableId() {
    int id = 0;
    while(this.getStartedIds().contains(id)){
        id++;
    }
    return id;
}

}
```

If my jar do something really simple such as create a file, it works nice. But if it's more complex, the thread just stops working, the cpu fall to 0%. It depends on what i ask. For some task it can run 30-35seconds before the issue happens for others such as doing

```
while(true);
```

It stopped a few seconds latter.

I thought it was something like a timeout, but actually it is not a constant time. Maybe something like memory issue...?

I have tried to run the same code outside the springboot server (on a simple java project main that launch Memory.start() and it works well. So I supposed it was a spring boot misunderstanding from my side. If someone know how to make this jar run independently from the springboot server just tell me please.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution. I had to place a

```
p.waitFor();
```

so the thread launching the jar will not stop. Then, the input and the output of the jar are not connected to the input/output of the lauching thread, then, i had to create an other thread to monitor the output of the jar (it actually print it in the main thread). I found those informations here : http://labs.excilys.com/2012/06/26/runtime-exec-pour-les-nuls-et-processbuilder/
I still don't really understand why it was working outside the springboot server, actually it should not have run...

If somebody is interested, here is my code.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

class AfficheurFlux implements Runnable {

private final InputStream inputStream;

AfficheurFlux(InputStream inputStream) {
    this.inputStream = inputStream;
}

private BufferedReader getBufferedReader(InputStream is) {
    return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
}

@Override
public void run() {
    BufferedReader br = getBufferedReader(inputStream);
    String ligne = "";
    try {
        while ((ligne = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(ligne);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}


public class Memory {

private ArrayList<Integer> startedIds;

public ArrayList<Integer> getStartedIds() {
    return startedIds;
}

public void setStartedIds(ArrayList<Integer> startedIds) {
    this.startedIds = startedIds;
}

public Memory() {
    this.startedIds = new ArrayList<>();
}

public Memory(ArrayList<Integer> arr) {
    this.startedIds = arr;
}

public int startJar() {
    int id = this.findAvailableId();
    this.getStartedIds().add(id);
    System.out.println("i'm going to start with a big command!");
    String[] args = {"arg1","arg2", "arg3"};
    Launcher launcher = new Launcher("myJar.jar", args);
    launcher.start();
    return id;
}

private int findAvailableId() {
    int id = 0;
    while(this.getStartedIds().contains(id)){
        id++;
    }
    return id;
}






public class Launcher extends Thread{

private String jar;
private String[] args;

public AntLauncher(String jar, String[] args) {
    super();
    this.jar = jar;
    this.args = args;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    runJar(this.getJar(), this.getArgs());

}

private void runJar(String jar, String[] args){
    try {
        String[] s = new String[3+args.length];
        s[0] = "java";
        s[1] = "-jar";
        s[2] = jar;
        for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++){
            s[i+3] = args[i];
        }
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(s);
         AfficheurFlux fluxSortie = new AfficheurFlux(p.getInputStream());
         AfficheurFlux fluxErreur = new AfficheurFlux(p.getErrorStream());

            new Thread(fluxSortie).start();
            new Thread(fluxErreur).start();

            p.waitFor();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Fin du programme");
        }
    }
}
```